TypeError: cannot pickle 'builtins.DT' object - multiprocessing, pickle, pathos
I'm using "startinpy" library (https://startinpy.readthedocs.io/en/0.10.2/) in my project. It generally works great, but when I want to use it in second process, the pickle error shows up:
TypeError: cannot pickle 'builtins.DT' object
MRE:
import startinpy
from multiprocessing import Process


    class WorkCl:
        def __init__(self):
            self.dtm = DTM()  # PROCESS
            self.dtm.start()
            time.sleep(1)
    
    
    class DTM(Process):
        def __init__(self):
            Process.__init__(self)
            self.dt = startinpy.DT()
    
    
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        wcl = WorkCl()

Does anyone know, how to make this work? I need to use the "dt" object as class object, because I'm using it inside various class methods. Also I'm using multiprocessing Event object to stop the process and SharedMemory and ShareableList to share informations between processes.
I have found library called "pathos" (https://pathos.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pathos.html) but I don't understand how exactly replace the standard multiprocessing module with it. Can anyone help?

Not sure I fully understand your use case but IMHO there's no need to use DTM class, a valid approach can be to use a static method in WorkCl class to instantiate your DT object:
import startinpy
from multiprocessing import Process


class WorkCl:
    def __init__(self):
        self.dtm_process = Process(target=self.run_dtm)
        # processes are spawned by creating a Process object and then calling its start() method
        self.dtm_process.start()
    
    @staticmethod
    def create_dt():
        # create DT object
        return startinpy.DT()

    def run_dtm(self):
        # Initialize the startinpy.DT object within the process
        self.dt = self.create_dt()
        print("DTM process started")
        print("DTM process ending")

    def stop(self):
        # Properly terminate the process
        self.dtm_process.terminate()  
        self.dtm_process.join() 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    wcl = WorkCl()

